# Mule ESB: How to use DataMapper with Global bean

Tags: mule

I'm on Mule ESB 3.6 EE. 
Trying to figure out how to leverage DataMapper component for populating properties of a global bean.

Basically, I have a bean defined like this:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="testBean" name="testBean" class="com.test.MyTest" scope="prototype"/>
</spring:beans>
```

and I would like to populate it with using DataMapper. However, I can't figure out how to specify the bean object name (testBean) in the mapper wizard. The only option I can see is POJO where I can specify the class name but not the particular bean name.

So, any ideas how this could be solved?

Comment: This looks like a invalid use case, the bean's dependencies (properties) need to populating when the spring application context is created (Mule start up), this cannot and should not be done using the data mapper. Have a read of the spring bean and spring container life cycle and you should be able to design your application better

Comment: May be I wasn't clear enough... You can specify the bean's life cycle when you define the bean. And then you can call a java class that would access the bean's properties - nothing wrong with it, it's a standard technique. The only difference is that I'm trying using DataMapper for the purpose rather than writing another java class that would update the bean with the payload data.

Comment: The purpose of the datamapper is to "transform" the payload from one type to another (XML->JSON,POJO->POJO and so on)... you are trying to use it to invoke a method on a spring bean with a specific argument ? ... something seems amiss

Comment: No, I'm trying to do the mapping straight to the bean with a pre-defined lifecycle. The bean is the same pojo just defined with a particular lifecycle. To be more clear. Let's say you are mapping from map to POJO. Where is the result pojo is stored? So, I wanna store it in the global bean.

Comment: Then do the transformation first using the data mapper and then set the new payload into your bean using a component

Comment: Ok, how to set the payload into the bean?

Comment: Use [invoke component](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/invoke-component-reference) use this if the payload you are passing in is needed as a method argument (transient for one operation), if you are going to use this to set up state (class variable) inside the bean, then I think your design is flawed.

Comment: And what you believe would be the benefit of using DataMapper then?

Comment: Don't get your question sorry

Comment: The original question was about a possibility of utilising DataMapper for updating properties of a global bean. What you proposing is manually populating the properties of the bean. In addition, you propose first put the data to the payload pojo with DataMapper. Looks little bit strange to me. You don't need Datamapper or pojo in the payload if you still "manually" populate the bean properties via expression (as I would do it) or via invoke (as you propose). But the point was to leverage the DataMapper for the purpose rather than doing a "manual" mapping.